# Can i use a 19V 4A adapter for my 12V 4A control board?

Tags: power-supply, lcd, monitor

I recently bought a control board for my lcd panel that needs 12 V, 4 A however the power adapter I have is 19 V 4 A. Would it blow the control board/lcd panel if i was to use the power adapter?

Comment: If it could take 19V it would tell you.

Comment: Applying 19 volts to a device designed to operate on 12 volts will very likely damage the device.

Comment: Why not just check the specification of your board or take advices from your supplier? Of course, the last attempt is just plug your 19 volts adapter and see what will happen, but please be ready for the smoke.

Comment: I found a 12v 2a power supply and the lcd pannel turns on but had a whole bunch on red dots all over the place is this because of the missing amp?

Comment: @JoeGoe its impossible to know, you haven't provided any information about this lcd panel or this control board or pictures of the dots

Comment: We don't know which boars you bought so we don't know what specs it has, so we can't answer your question. Please provide the information or read the manual.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @brhans I answered without looking for a duplicate. The duplicate you flagged is excellent, but I don't have Close Vote privileges so I'll leave my answer and take whatever points I get :-)

Answer (score 0):

The three key values in power requirements are voltage (Volts = V), current (Amps = A) and the type of power (AC vs. DC).

Many devices can handle a wide range of voltage, but if a device does not state that it can (e.g., many laptop or other consumer electronic power supplies can take a range of 100V - 240V which allows use of the same power supply around the world) then it generally can't handle much variation. If the supplied voltage is too low, the device will probably not work. If the supplied voltage is too high, the device will probably not work and *may be permanently damaged*, possibly with catastrophic results.

Current is a different story altogether. Generally speaking, a power supply can supply any current up to the rated maximum, and as long as that rated maximum is equal to or higher than the powered device's requirements everything will work fine. There are some exceptions - e.g., some devices require extra current at startup and some power supplies are designed to provide that extra current without a problem, while some will fail. If your power supply can't supply the necessary current, it may fail safe (overcurrent protection) it may fail catastrophically, it may provide the maximum it can provide and the device just won't work properly, or it may provide the requested power but degrade over time and wear out prematurely.

AC vs. DC? Get that wrong and a catastrophic failure is quite possible.